# How i select each variable in sequence from a string?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I insert a string like that in a procedure:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
con = FunctionConnection()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "GetVerification"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

If ValueSingleBracket = "Flexible" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "1,2,47,48,49,50,52")
ElseIf ValueSingleBracket = "Rigid" Then 
Dim Header_DataReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
con.Open()
Header_DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

My procedure is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetVerification (@Value VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @a TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON))
    INSERT INTO @a
    SELECT t.c.value('.', 'INT')
    FROM (SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(@Value, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)) r
    CROSS APPLY r.x.nodes('/t') t(c)

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.CP_Sequence
    WHERE ParagraphOrder IN (SELECT * FROM @a)
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)

END
```

How do I select the procedure to each variable from last to first but in order:

I would like the procedure to select me this:

```
1,2,47,48,49,50,52
```

But he takes my values when I read in this order:

```
47,48,49,50,52,1,2
```

When i try to insert each value in table first value from string is 47 not 1, how i do to select first value, 1?

All data for insert here:

```
Dim SingleBracket As RadioButtonList = gvr.FindControl("RBL_Buckle_Single_Bracket type")

Dim count3 As Integer = SingleBracket.Items.Count
Dim ValueSingleBracket As String = Nothing

For i = 0 To count3 - 1

If SingleBracket.Items(i).Selected = True Then

    ValueSingleBracket = SingleBracket.Items(i).Value

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    con = FunctionConnection()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "GetVerification"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    If ValueSingleBracket = "Flexible" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "1,2,47,48,49,50,52")
    ElseIf ValueSingleBracket = "Rigid" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "1,2,47,48,49,50,51,53")
    ElseIf ValueSingleBracket = "Webbing" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "1,2,45,46,68,69,70,71")
    End If

    Dim Header_DataReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    con.Open()
    Header_DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If Header_DataReader.HasRows Then
        Do While Header_DataReader.Read

            a = a + 1

            Dim Description As String = Nothing
            Dim ActivityName As String = Nothing
            Dim RequirementNom As String = Nothing
            Dim ActivityResource As String = Nothing
            Dim ParagraphOrder As Integer = Nothing

            If Header_DataReader.IsDBNull(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("Description")) = False Then
                Description = Header_DataReader.GetValue(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("Description"))
            End If
            If Header_DataReader.IsDBNull(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("ActivityName")) = False Then
                ActivityName = Header_DataReader.GetValue(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("ActivityName"))
            End If
            If Header_DataReader.IsDBNull(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("RequrementNom")) = False Then
                RequirementNom = Header_DataReader.GetValue(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("RequrementNom"))
            End If
            If Header_DataReader.IsDBNull(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("ActivityResource")) = False Then
                ActivityResource = Header_DataReader.GetValue(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("ActivityResource"))
            End If
            If Header_DataReader.IsDBNull(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("ParagraphOrder")) = False Then
                ParagraphOrder = Header_DataReader.GetValue(Header_DataReader.GetOrdinal("ParagraphOrder"))
            End If

            Dim InsertConnection As SqlConnection = Nothing
            InsertConnection = FunctionConnection()
            Dim cmdIns As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            cmdIns.Connection = InsertConnection
            cmdIns.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdIns.CommandText = "InsertValidation"

            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", RowID)
            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description)
            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivityName", ActivityName)
            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequirementNom", RequirementNom)
            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivityResource", ActivityResource)
            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParagraphOrder", ParagraphOrder)
            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderSelection", a)

            Try
                InsertConnection.Open()
                cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                LBL_Error.Text = "Error insertion !"
            Finally
                If InsertConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    InsertConnection.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        Loop
        con.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ParagraphOrder`

Comment: You shoud more specific where

Comment: I suppose after `WHERE` :)

Comment: I try after where but doesn't work

Comment: Please provide `DDL` for your table and small data sample

Comment: Also check about `Table-Valued Parameters`

Comment: Yes i cheked Table Valued and i put Order by parahraphOrder and work, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome and have a nice coding ;)

Comment: You too sir, have a nice day!

Comment: if have string like that: 1,2,144,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,19,20,21,22,25,27, and i want that order? 1,2 and 144 next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID INT, OrderID INT)
INSERT INTO @a
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'INT'), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)
FROM (SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(@Value, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)) r
CROSS APPLY r.x.nodes('/t') t(c)

SELECT s.*
FROM dbo.CP_Sequence s
JOIN @a a ON s.ParagraphOrder = a.ID
ORDER BY a.OrderID
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use ORDER BY in your Procedure Body Before END

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.CP_Sequence
WHERE ParagraphOrder IN (SELECT * FROM @a)
ORDER BY ParagraphOrder
```

If your list is string type then go throgh below one.

```
DECLARE @IND Int, @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result TABLE (Value BIGINT)
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(MAX)='1,2,144,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,19,20,21,22,25,27';

        SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
        WHILE @ind > 0
        BEGIN
              SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
              SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
              INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
        END
        SET @str = @input
        INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
        SELECT STUFF(   (SELECT  ','+cast(Value as varchar) FROM @Result
       ORDER BY Value FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: if have string like that: 1,2,144,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,19,20,21,22,25,27, and i want that order?

Comment: I have edited my answer if your input is string type. Better you put the code in Function for re-usability.

Comment: Thanks, this is it, have a nice day!